# How to convert a k value to an angle?

Tags: number-theory, functions, trigonometry, polar-coordinates, angle

I'm trying to use $f'(x)$ in a ecuation wear it need to be converted to be used sort like $cos(g(f'(x)))$ whear $g(x) = y$ rad or deg

What I'm currently working on is to get this ecuation to work with horizontal lines.
$$f (x) ^ 2 + x ^ 2 ) ^ .5 ( f (x) / ( f (x) ^ 2 + x ^ 2 ) ^ .5 = y$$
And that is is the same as $f(x)=y$

Comment: Please, correct the title, it raises supernatural expectations :)

Comment: Resisting the urge to correct where angels fear to tread...

Comment: I did think it looked weird. I did type it on the phone in a hurry

Comment: Please clarify what you're asking for.  For the equation, do you mean to say this...

$$y = \sqrt {((f(x)^2 + x^2)}) \times \frac {f(x)}{\sqrt {(f(x)^2 + x^2)}}$$

and are you looking for the derivative?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to convert the derivative to an angle.

Comment: Putting Pythagoras in the garlic? As you like ... hahaha

Check the parentheses.